# Hadoop write directory

Tags: configuration, hadoop, directory, storage

Simple question but reading through documentation and configuration I can't quite seem to figure it out.

How do I A) know where hadoop is writing to on the local disk and B) change that

For initial testing I setup HDFS on a 20gb linux VM - to it we've added a 500gb networked drive for moving towards prototyping the full system.  So now how do I point HDFS at that drive, or do I simply move the home directory/install with some slight change in setup and restart the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hadoop.tmp.dir` holds the default directories.

[See the default core-default docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.0/core-default.html).

You can change the `core-site.xml` file to set it (you could probably change it other places as well; that's just where I happen to do it–I don't know if it's the "best" place to set that or not).